# AWS S3 Temporary Credentials expiring before upload finishes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I request temporary credentials from AWS S3 to let the client upload files. The client is a boto3 lib that does Multipart Upload.
My problem is that if the file is too large and the connection is slow the upload does not finish in the allocated time and fails with the 403 error code on Complete Multipart Upload, which is called by boto3 internally.
I would expect that the expiration time applied to the start of the whole upload operation but apparently this is not the case.
Is there a way around it besides allocating larger expiration time ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115281/handling-aws-sts-key-expiration-while-a-file-transfer-to-aws-s3 ?

Comment: `expiration time applied to the start of the whole upload operation` yes that should be the case.  `fails with the 403 .. on Complete Multipart` if you call the operation after expiration, sure. As far I know the default aws-sdk client should renew the credentials itself when expired, but if the presigned urls are used, new values need to be generated.  If it's not the case, then the credentials need to be renewed